# Why is my JSON invalid?

Tags: json, mongodb, parsing

I feel really stupid for asking this, but I can't figure out at all what's wrong with this JSON. It's a series of documents returned by a mongoDB server from a GET request:

```
{ __v: 0,
  _id: 59234b9737d68fcd1b6cd62c,
  UId: '58f8954c3602b80552b6f1fb',
  SerialNumber: 'IIOJOIMJ',
  ChildName: 'TEST',
  created_at: Mon May 22 2017 22:35:35 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  updatedAt: Mon May 22 2017 22:35:35 GMT+0200 (CEST) },{ __v: 0,
  _id: 592354b197312b7f1e1e250b,
  UId: '58f8954c3602b80552b6f1fb',
  SerialNumber: 'IIOJOIMJ555',
  ChildName: 'TEST2',
  created_at: Mon May 22 2017 23:14:25 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  updatedAt: Mon May 22 2017 23:14:25 GMT+0200 (CEST) }
```

I already tried some online JSON validators, but they keep giving me this error (which is probably right, but i can't interpret it):

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
 {  __v: 0,     _id: 59234
----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: i accidentally pasted the document 2 times

Comment: hint some quotes are probably missing around the dates

Comment: It's not JSON at all. It's a JavaScript object.

Comment: You can always use something like this to [validate](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) JSON

Comment: That is probably the case! Do you have any idea how i could parse an element out of this?

Comment: You don't need to parse it at all. You just access the elements in the object that Mongo returns.

Comment: like this: `list = data.SerialNumber` ?

Comment: How are you picking this up? This looks like console.log() output rather than anything that tried to export as JSON.

Comment: If you get more than one result, you have an array. You have to choose which one to access (`data[0].SerialNumber`) or loop through each of them.

Comment: @JJJ's answer is correct. `data.SerialNumber` isn't defined, because an array doesn't have a property named `SerialNumber`. However, the elements of the array do.

Comment: @JJJ Is it possible to get the array in plaintext? if i try `JSON.stringify(data)` it still gives me an `undefined`

Comment: Without seeing what you're trying to do, it's not really possible to say what the problem is. For some reason you keep trying to force JSON into this when the Mongo response has nothing to do with JSON; I'm 99% sure that it's the main cause of your problems. I suggest you open a new question with the actual code that you use to query the database and a clear explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I got it to work with this: `data[1].SerialNumber` Thanks!

Comment: @JJJ I'm really sorry for my confusing explaination. This is my first porject working with a MEAN stack, and I got confused because the output looked a lot like JSON. But you answers really pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

While this JSON might parse OK in JavaScript, the [JSON specification](http://json.org) requires quotes around the keys.

```
{ "__v": 0, ... }
```

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't. when i do something like `list = data.SerialNumber` i get `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Valid json has keys in double quotes. Put all your json keys, the names before the semicolons, in "".